# How to design for multiple device form factors using Project Clarity?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I've begun using Project Clarity in a new web application, and I would like this application to provide a good UX on various form factors (desktop, table, smartphone).

A simple example: when displaying a Datagrid component, I would like to display more columns for desktop and fewer for smartphone.

What is the recommended approach for a Clarity-based app to detect and ***customize*** for different form factors?

Comment: The Clarity design system is an enterprise first design system with graceful fallbacks for smaller than desktop screens. You asked about the datagrid. Imo - as forcing a user to use a datagrid on a phone is a horrible user experience. Having tried to use Google sheets once or twice on my phone in a crunch it was less than ideal and, personally, I would not make it part of an apps experience. One option that comes to mind for you to try is use the hidable columns feature and based on your form factor set the hidden/shown columns accordingly.

Comment: @hippeelee Thank you, and I completely agree with you.  I do not want to present mobile users with a wide datagrid with many columns. Actually, I only intend to show 2 columns to mobile users.  The only reason I'm using a datagrid in the first place is to make use of features such as expandable rows so that detailed information can be hidden until a row is expanded.  But I don't know how to code my templates so that they understand when a user is on a mobile vs. a desktop, for example.

Comment: What if your app used conditional properties to hide the columns for each form factor?